# How to control the caption of algorithm2e by captionsetup?

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

I want to change the appearance of the caption for algorithms written by `algorithm2e` package using the `caption` package.
In `captionsetup` one can easily customize the caption depending on the float type, whether a table, a figure, or a longtable even, but when I specified a captionsetup for algorrithms it didn't work, is there any way to change the `Algorithm 1:` to `Algorithm 1.`?

**MWE Code:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{justification=justified} % works fine
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,format=plain, font={small}} % works fine
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelsep=period,format=plain} % didn't work!
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the command

```
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{.}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{justification=justified} % works fine
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,format=plain, font={small}} % works fine
%\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelsep=period,format=plain} % didn't work!
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{.}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

P.S. An extract from the `caption` package documentation:

> *Note:* Some environments, e.g. the `algorithm` environment offered by the `algorithm2e` package,
>   might react allergic to a change of the caption label format.

Comment: Section **9.2.2 setting style and layout of algorithm, caption and title** (p 22) of the [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf).

Comment: when I changed the caption to `.`, I noticed that the counting numbers were not reset for each chapter of the book as was before. Is that what allergic means?

Comment: @doctorate It might be one of the collateral effects...

Comment: Am I mistaken or does this just answer the specific style and not the general question of how to use captionsetup?